# Laravel Nova does not distinguish between different types of polymorphic relationship between same models

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, polymorphic-relationship

I have a `Tab` model which has a one-to-many polymorphic relationship with many other models including my `User` model. I've called this relationship `customizers` (because they customize a tab's content) and store them in a table called `tab_customizers` with `customizer_id` and `customizer_type` as relation-related columns. Because this relation also can have different types with the same model, I've included another column called `relation_type`.

For example, between my `Tab` and `User` models, there are 2 different relations:

- A `User` can relate to a `Tab` as its `author` (if the related user write a post, it'll be displayed in the tab)
- A `User` can relate to a `Tab` as its focused `mention` (if the related user is mentioned in a post, it'll be displayed in the tab)

Here are my relations defined in the `Tab` model:

```php
public function authors()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'customizer', 'tab_customizers')->where('relation_type', 'author');
}

public function mentions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'customizer', 'tab_customizers')->where('relation_type', 'mention');
}
```

And here are my Nova fields in my `Tab` resource:

```php
MorphedByMany::make('authors', User::class),

MorphedByMany::make('mentions', User::class),
```

Here is my issue: When I select a `User` model to attach it to `mentions` (actually to `customizers` with `mention` as its `relation_type`), it'll attach with `author` as `relation_type`. How can I make Nova distinguish between these 2 types?

Besides, I can't have a relation between `Tab` and `User` with `author` as `relation_type` and another with `mention` as `relation_type` at the same time. When I try (using tinker) to attach a relation of one of the types while a relation of the other type already exists, it will update the existing relationship and does not attach a new one.